# Let X be a Random Variable with probability distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let X be a Random Variable with probability distribution

X      -1,      0,       1,         2,          3

F(x)   .125,    .5,      .2,       .05,        0.125,

a) Find E(x) and V(X)
b) find the probability function Y=3X-1 and then find E(Y) & V(X)
c) find the probability function Z=3X+2 and then find E(Z) & V(Y)

I've done the a part
E(x)= 0.55
V (X) = 1.3475

can someone please guide be with the b and c part?

Answer (score 1):

The answers to (a) are correct. Either that or we have made the same mistake.

The problems (b) and (c) seem to be about the same. Presumably the mean and variance of $Y$ are asked for, and then the mean and variance of $Z$.

There is an easy way to find the mean and variance of $Y$, and a hard way. First the easy way. We have
$$E(Y)=E(3X-1)=3E(X)-1.$$
Since you know $E(X)$, you are essentially finished. The result we have used is that if $a$ and $b$ are constants, then $E(aX+b)=aE(X)+b$.

For the variance, we have
$$\operatorname{Var}(Y)=\operatorname{Var}(3X-1)=9\operatorname{Var}(X).$$
The result we have used is that $\operatorname{Var}(aX+b)=a^2\operatorname{Var}(X)$.

But it looks as if they may want you to do things the hard way, since they ask for the probability distribution of $Y$. So we will do that, briefly.

Recall that $X$ takes on the values $-1$, $0$, $1$, $2$, $3$ with certain known probabilities that we will not list.  So $Y$, that is, $3X-1$, takes on the values $3(-1)-1, 3(0)-1, 3(1)-1, 3(2)-1, 3(3)-1$ with these same probabilities.

Thus the possible values of $Y$ are $-4,-1,2,5,8$,  with known probabilities. Now to compute mean and variance you can make the same calculations with these numbers as the ones you did for $X$.